# Adicionar linha em JTable ao clicar do botão

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Estou iniciando em criação de interface em Java, um exemplo que estou tentando fazer é ter um formulário com `textField` `nome` e `email`, e ao clicar no botão de `Enviar` os dados desses `textField` vai para a minha `JTable`, mas não estou conseguindo manipular a minha tabela, segue o código da última tentativa:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

/** * @author Rosicléia Frasson */
public class teste01 extends JFrame {

    JPanel painelFundo;
    JTable tabela; // minha tabela
    private JTextField nome;
    private JLabel txtnome;
    private JLabel txtemail;
    private JTextField email;
    private JButton enviar;
    private JButton cancelar;

    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tabela.getModel(); //pega modelo da tabela

    private int dado = 0;

    public teste01() {



        enviar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(!nome.getText().equals("") && !email.getText().equals(""))
                {
                    nome.setText("stack"); // apenas para ver se entrou na condição

                    modelo.addColumn("Nome"); // era para adicionar as colunas
                    modelo.addColumn("Email");

                   /* dados[dado][0] = nome.getText();
                    dados[dado][1] = email.getText();
                    dado += 1;
                    tabela = new JTable(dados, colunas);
                    tabela.repaint();*/
                }
            }
        });
        cancelar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                nome.setText("");
                email.setText("");
            }
        });
        painelFundo.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        });
    }

    // cria minha interface
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("teste01");
        frame.setContentPane(new teste01().painelFundo);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Já pensou em criar seu proprio Tablemodel? Estou elaborando uma resposta sobre isso em outra pergunta, talvez ajude. DefaulTableModel é uma sujeira tamanha, além de deixar o código mais lento.

Comment: Antes eu tentei implementando um próprio vendo alguns exemplos. Mas não deu certo, a tabela na interface fica em branco. Nem as colunas são adicionadas.

Comment: Assim que puder te respondo, mas precisaria saber se nome e email faz parte de algum tipo de entidade, ou objeto, exemplo: pessoaCadastro. Tendo um objeto como foco, fica mais fácil de criar um tablemodel. Tenho alguns modelos prontos até, só modificaria eles.

Comment: `email` e `nome` são textField da mesma classe(inteface), não vêm de nenhuma entidade ou objeto externo. Como citei na pergunta, é um exemplo simples, uma única classe que tem na interface dois textField(nome e email), dois botões (enviar, cancelar) e uma FTable (tabela). O objetivo é só ao clicar em Enviar, pegar o nome e email do textField e colocar na tabela como uma nova linha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está usando `DefaulTableModel`, basta chamar o método [**`addRow()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#addRow-java.lang.Object:A-), passando um vetor de `Strings` com o valor dos dois campos:

```
String[] novaLinha = {nome.getText(), email.getText()};
modelo.addRow(novaLinha);
```

O próprio `DefaultTableModel` se encarregará de notificar os listeners e redesenhar sua tabela com a nova linha.

Comment: Eu tinha tentado assim  e não deu.

Comment: @lvcs esse método é perfeitamente funcional, até criei um exemplo aqui para testar que funcionaria realmente antes de postar. Talvez o problema esteja em outro lugar, como por exemplo, você está adicionando a tabela em um JScrollpane?? Adicione uns prints do problema para ver se da pra identificá-lo.

Comment: Eu tentei com e sem a tabela dentro do JScrollPane, estou seguindo esses passos: Declado um novo DefaultTableModel, seto o modelo da tabela como o novo DefaultTableModel, adiciono uma nova linha no Model, e nada acontece, não é adicionada, não é apresentado nenhum erro nem no console.

Tentei de várias formas, mas não consigo criar elementos na tabela, ela fica em branco desde o começo do programa.

Comment: O código é praticamente esse descrito na pergunta. Mas não aparece nenhuma linha ou coluna na tabela, ela estando ou não dentro do JScrollPane

Comment: @lvcs poste o código da tela onde você constroi sua tabela por completo na pergunta, o problema deve estar em outro lugar do código. Com ele completo, fica mais facil analisar.

Answer (score 0):

Eu estada tentando a mesma coisa e na ação do botão para adicionar botei o seguinte código.

```
DefaultTableModel nada = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

 nada.addRow(new Object[]{null,null});
```